# cesmlm.dll not loading in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am new to using Visual Studio. "cesmlm.dll" is being used by my program to access an USB printer. On Debugging, this dll is not being loaded. 
I have tried setting the Environment Path in project properties -> Configuration properties -> Debugging.
I have tried placing this .dll in the project folder , my output folder where the exe is generated and everywhere possible... but all in vain :(.
Could someone please help me on this? TIA .

**Platform : Visual C++, 
OS : Windows 7, 
Visual Studio version : 2012**

Comment: Did you add the path to the linker?

Comment: Do you mean the output file path under Linker? that i have set. I am not sure if i have missed out any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably because my Module machine is of 32bits while the .dll that i am trying to load is of 64bits.

Edit -  After replacing the dll with a 32 bit dll , issue has been resolved. Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: Remember that you can not link 32 bit code to a 64 bit application or viseversa. Also with Visual Studio is best to only use libraries from the same version of VisualStudio and not to mix Release and Debug since any of this can cause heap corruption.

Comment: Yes, the issue was because I was linking a 64 bit dll to a 32 bit application. This dll is generated from my printer's driver, and it automatically generated a 64 bit dll as mine is a 64 bit OS.
Issue was resolved after I installed the driver on a 32 bit machine , took the dll and replaced in mine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get you didn't add the dll to the linkers path. It needs to know where you store the dll in order to link against it.

Go to Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories

Click Edit there to add the path to your dll.

Comment: I have already placed my dll in the paths given in VC++ Directories-> Library Directories , but it doesnt work. And the description for Library Directories says "Corresponds to environment variable LIB" . So is field meant for lib files only?